# Why is my .editorconfig file being ignored?

Tags: visual-studio-mac, editorconfig

I am using Visual Studio for Mac, 8.3.4 (build 8)

I have a very simple Visual Studio solution with one small project. I followed the docs exactly to create my .editorconfig file, but when I do Edit -> Format -> Format Document, my options are ignored.

This is my .editorconfig file:

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 20
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

And here is proof it is in the correct location:

[image]

Comment: What's the actual file path of `.editorconfig` and its relationship with your solution file or project file? The screen shot is less obvious, as a node under Solution Items can present anywhere on the disk.

Comment: As Lex has suggested, the location of the .editorconfig file is important. It would need to be either in the same directory as your solution file (.sln) or any directory above that (which contains the solution's directory).

Comment: also why is updating vscode enough to break editorconfig. It is super irritating since it randomly decides that it will stop using editorconfig and makes my each parentheses on a new like which is super annoying for me to look at